# How to create a leaderboard from a text file using OOP in python?

Tags: python, sorting, oop, pygame, leaderboard

i am fairly new to python and am making a game which requires reading information from a text file and turning it in to a leaderboard sorted by the highest to lowest score with the name of the person next to each score. The .txt file looks like this:

bob,100

cat,300

dog,80

mouse,50

It also has to be OOP so any help would be greatley appreciated . :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @davo36 I have tried code from different sources and tried editing it but it's getting me anywhere apart from confusion. A lot of them use JSON and I would rather not but if it's necessary I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the text file line by line and put the values into a list of tuples. Ignore the empty lines. Use string.split() to split line into two values.

Each entry is a tuple (, ). Make sure to convert the score from string to int. You can then sort the list by score.

```
def load_data(file_name):
    result = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            values = line.strip().split(',')
            if len(values) == 2:
                name, score = values
                result.append((name, int(score)))
    return sorted(result, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

To make it OOP, just make your Leaderboard into a class with methods to load, update data, create bitmap to display, and so on.